Block sync fail after Async backing
after upgrading the async backing runtime upgrade (at block 35), my local parachain can continue to generate the block. However, when I run another archive node by the binary that supports the async backing or the previous one on the same machine, the sync process fails and shows the below error. Does anyone encounter the same situation?
Aug 26 13:51:39 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:39 [Parachain]  Verification failed for block 0x2ede9d2dacadb4da82d2570a89ba46bd12db4f7918928e581b14be6bec396b59 received from (12D3KooWPmr3uZzZH7sVHpYsr7GV2CGoxAHb17my8rYz9Wz9yGck): "Header 0x2ede9d2dacadb4da82d2570a89ba46bd12db4f7918928e581b14be6bec396b59 rejected: too far in the future"
Aug 26 13:51:39 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:39 [Parachain]  Error importing block 0x236b524e114a692110ace6404d4bc0a43f83428d39833bff19171b1c0157f670: block has an unknown parent
Aug 26 13:51:39 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:39 [Parachain] Reserved peer 12D3KooWPmr3uZzZH7sVHpYsr7GV2CGoxAHb17my8rYz9Wz9yGck disconnected
Aug 26 13:51:39 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:39 [Parachain]  Verification failed for block 0x2ede9d2dacadb4da82d2570a89ba46bd12db4f7918928e581b14be6bec396b59 received from (12D3KooWSRxK5D4mhQuRNK4apVERP5zN2rNTferProbTtLWNxf6X): "Header 0x2ede9d2dacadb4da82d2570a89ba46bd12db4f7918928e581b14be6bec396b59 rejected: too far in the future"
Aug 26 13:51:39 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:39 [Parachain]  Verification failed for block 0x2ede9d2dacadb4da82d2570a89ba46bd12db4f7918928e581b14be6bec396b59 received from (12D3KooWPmr3uZzZH7sVHpYsr7GV2CGoxAHb17my8rYz9Wz9yGck): "Header 0x2ede9d2dacadb4da82d2570a89ba46bd12db4f7918928e581b14be6bec396b59 rejected: too far in the future"
Aug 26 13:51:39 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:39 [Parachain] Reserved peer 12D3KooWPmr3uZzZH7sVHpYsr7GV2CGoxAHb17my8rYz9Wz9yGck disconnected
Aug 26 13:51:40 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:40 [Parachain]  Verification failed for block 0x2ede9d2dacadb4da82d2570a89ba46bd12db4f7918928e581b14be6bec396b59 received from (12D3KooWSRxK5D4mhQuRNK4apVERP5zN2rNTferProbTtLWNxf6X): "Header 0x2ede9d2dacadb4da82d2570a89ba46bd12db4f7918928e581b14be6bec396b59 rejected: too far in the future"
Aug 26 13:51:40 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:40 [Parachain]  Verification failed for block 0x2ede9d2dacadb4da82d2570a89ba46bd12db4f7918928e581b14be6bec396b59 received from (12D3KooWPmr3uZzZH7sVHpYsr7GV2CGoxAHb17my8rYz9Wz9yGck): "Header 0x2ede9d2dacadb4da82d2570a89ba46bd12db4f7918928e581b14be6bec396b59 rejected: too far in the future"
Aug 26 13:51:40 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:40 [Parachain] Reserved peer 12D3KooWPmr3uZzZH7sVHpYsr7GV2CGoxAHb17my8rYz9Wz9yGck disconnected
Aug 26 13:51:41 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:41 [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #783 (0xc2d3…73b4), finalized #781 (0xf373…8628), ⬇ 4.2kiB/s ⬆ 2.2kiB/s
Aug 26 13:51:41 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:41 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #35 (0x838c…abff), finalized #0 (0x94a1…f147), ⬇ 243.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.8kiB/s
Aug 26 13:51:42 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:42 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #784 (0xa1a7…5818)
Aug 26 13:51:42 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:42 [Parachain] Reserved peer 12D3KooWPmr3uZzZH7sVHpYsr7GV2CGoxAHb17my8rYz9Wz9yGck disconnected
Aug 26 13:51:46 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:46 [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #784 (0xa1a7…5818), finalized #782 (0x97ed…c888), ⬇ 3.5kiB/s ⬆ 1.6kiB/s
Aug 26 13:51:46 ip-20-0-50-47 start_para_node.sh[285151]: 2024-08-26 13:51:46 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #35 (0x838c…abff), finalized #0 (0x94a1…f147), ⬇ 0.5kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s


I experienced a similar issue previously. I believe it happens because there are still some nodes operating on the old version, causing them to spread invalid data. I resolved it by restarting the node to clear the p2p cache, and then everything functioned properly.
Also, I noticed that your parachain peers count is 0, which seems incorrect. Please verify that; I think once you acquire some peers, it will work as expected.

Thanks for your reply. That's a little weird because, in my local environment, only one collator and one full node encountered the issue. I don't think there are other nodes on the old version.
About the peer count, the peer became zero, I guess because "after the too far in the future error" happened, the process dropped the peers.
2024-08-26 14:13:21 [Parachain] ⚙️  Preparing, target=#338 (2 peers) ....     
2024-08-26 14:13:23 [Parachain] ... too far in the future"    


Oh, you are right! The fix steps are as you said. 1. Run the command and your node will be stuck in that block. 2. Stop the command 3. Rerun the command, and it will continue to sync with other blocks. Thanks a lot for your reply!
